# Retrieving objects with associations in Spring JDBC

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-jdbc

I am fairly new to using Spring JDBC and I am going to retrieve objects from the database now which have associations to other objects (one-to-many, one-to-one...). I wonder what is the proper way of doing it? I have read this answer [Spring Framework JDBC DAO with agrgegation/composition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3085124/spring-framework-jdbc-dao-with-agrgegation-composition) which basically recommends using a ORM framework which I won't cause of performance and I find Spring JDBC quite pleasant to work with.

The original poster of the question showed an example of using one repository/dao method inside another dao/repository class. That would have been my guess of doing it too, but from what I understand you then use two different connections, and it could increase if you have other repositories as well. Is this bad even though using connection pooling provided by Glassfish?

I am not sure if I understand the answer given to the question either, nor if this is the proper way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring JDBC always used the same connection in the scope of a transaction, so you should not worry about the number of connections, you only  need to ensure that the load of the object occurs within a single transaction.

see `DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection()` if you are interested on how connections are retrieved from data source.

Comment: So the text in question about using multiple connections is wrong and using different repositories/dao is proper usage?

Comment: If you load the object in a single transaction (as it should be for isolation, not only for saving connections)